# Sybase error code 112116 unable to solve

Tags: sap-ase

A variable with char(20) and converting that variable to datetime 
values passed to that variable 'June-2013' and 'July-2013' etc.
All results are working but failing with one of the value that is 'August-2013'.
am getting the error code as sybase error code 112116
Could any one quickly help me out ?

Regards,
Sankar.

Comment: getting error as below
There was an error reading the results of the SQL statement.
The displayed results may be incorrect or incomplete.
Internal Ct-Lib/Cs-Lib error 33816853: 'cs_convert: cslib user api
layer: common library error: The conversion/operation resulted in
underflow.'.
Sybase error code=11216

Comment: Please share the code. Error is clear enough, you don't have enough space in the variable to store the value